# Где поставить филтр рекламы в Unity ADS. А так же с каким возрастом можно смотреть Рекламы казино?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, реклама

увидел что многих разработчиков Блокируют за то что у них реклама казино в играх а у них детская аудитория. Или же у них возрастная категория низкая.

суть вопроса:

1. Где поставить филитр рекламы? в Unity ADS(подробная инструкция)
2. С какого возраста можно смотреть рекламы Казино, и азартных игор!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С 18 лет. [Вот тут](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11987217?hl=ru#zippy=) можно подробно почитать по поводу рекламы.
Заголовок пункта: "Приложения, распространяемые в Google Play, которые содержат рекламу азартных игр, а также игр, конкурсов и турниров на реальные деньги"

По поводу создания фильтра:

Вы можете фильтровать рекламу, используя раздел [«Управление рекламой»](https://docs.unity.com/monetization-dashboard/AdControls.html) в представлении проекта на [панели разработчика](https://dashboard.unity3d.com/login?redirectTo=L21vbmV0aXphdGlvbg==).

Вы можете ограничить рекламу в Apple App Store и Google Play Store на основе возрастного рейтинга или категории приложения.
[Источник](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/213079383-Can-I-filter-Ads-that-appear-in-my-game-)